# How do i prove that something is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been asked to prove that given the vector space $\mathcal{L}(V,W)=\{f:V\rightarrow W\ |\ f\mathrm{\ is\ linear}\}$, with respect to pointwise operations, where $V,W$ are vector spaces, prove that $U=\{f\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)\ |\ f(v_o)=0,v_0\neq0,\mathrm{fixed}\}$is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.

First, I am unsure of what pointwise operations are. I'm thinking that they would be normal addition and scalar multiplication but for at fixed values of $f(x)$ but I can't be sure. Assuming I am correct, it is easy to show that $0$ is contained in $U$, where $0$ is the zero function, but I am having trouble showing that $f,g\in U,a,b\in\mathbb{F}\Rightarrow af+bg\in U$. Also, While writing this, I have come to realize that I am unsure of what $\mathbb{F}$ is.

Also, they want me to express $\dim(U)$ in terms of $\dim(V)$ and $\dim(W)$. How would I go about that?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I think pointwise operations just means the addition and scalar multiplication in $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is defined as
$$(f+ g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
and
$$(cf)(x) = cf(x)$$
for all linear transformations $f,g : V \to W$. I.e. you add and scalar multiply functions by adding/scalar multiplying at each point.

Answer (score 0):

Point-wise is just a fancy way of saying if I have $f,g\in\mathcal{L}$, then we define their addition $f+g$ by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, and similarly define $af$ by $(af)(x)=af(x)$ for any $a\in F$.

So, now like you said it's easy to see the zero function $0\in U$. And for $f,g\in U$, $a,b\in F$, we have

$$(af+bg)(v_0)=(af)(v_0)+(bg)(v_0)=af(v_0)+bg(v_0)=a\cdot 0+b\cdot 0=0$$

so it is indeed a subspace.